# Linear Algebra - Prove trival solution eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A is an $2\times2$ matrix with $\operatorname{trace}=1$, and $\det A=-6$.

Prove that $(2A+5I)x=0$ has only trival solution.

I need to show that $(-A-\frac{5}{2}I)x=0$ Therefore I need to show that $-\frac{5}{2}$ is not eigenvalue but how could I conclude that?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = \textrm{tr}\ A\\
\lambda_1 \lambda_2 = \det A$$

Suppose $\lambda_1 = -\frac{5}{2}$. Then can $\lambda_2$ satisfy those relationships?

Comment: I don't understand $$a_{11}+a_{22}=trA$$ But, $$detA = a_{11}*a_{22}-a_{21}*a_{12}$$.

Comment: The sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the trace. The product of the eigenvalues is equal to the determinant. These are fundamental properties.

Comment: this since matrix $A$ is similar to a matrix \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & 0\\
0 & a_{22} \\
\end{array}\right] right?

Comment: No, those properties are generally true for *all* square matrices.

Comment: Are you sure about these properties? $A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2\\
1 & 3\\
\end{array}\right]$ Therefore, $|A| = 1*3-1*2=1$ If I calculate it like $a_{11}*a_{22} \rightarrow 1*3 = 3 \neq 1$

Comment: Yes, I am sure about these properties. You are not computing the eigenvalues properly. The eigenvalues of $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$ are the roots of $(1-\lambda)(3-\lambda)-2=0$. The quadratic formula gives the roots as $\lambda_{1,2} = 2\pm \frac{\sqrt{12}}{2}$. Adding these together, we get $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 4$. Multiplying them together, we get $\lambda_1\lambda_2 = 4-\frac{\sqrt{12}^2}{2^2} = 4-3 = 1$.

Comment: My bad, Your right, Thank you for your help!